# How can I split this image into pieces so when I write a long text, it doesn't go outside of the div?

Tags: css

This is the image I'm talking about.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTkhd.jpg

Right now it works as a background of my news content. The brown area is the title, yellow are is the content.

When I write a long text into the content area, the text go out of the div because the picture isn't big enough.

I want to split the image into 3 pieces.

1. Header
2. Middle
3. Footer

Header and footer will always be applied once. Middle has to repeat itself depending on how long the text is.

How can I achieve this in CSS?

PS: You may call the split images "header.png, middle.png. and footer.png"

Comment: background-repeat: repeat-x should do the work another thing you can do is you just need to slice that image into 1px and repeat-x...saves you space...do you have a tool like Photoshop or Gimp? you might have to slice so it can be as you need...you might have to increase with Photoshop/Gimp

Comment: If that image gets cut up it doesn't look as if it will actually tile nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="parentDiv">
   <div id="header">
   </div>
   <div id="middle">
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
   </div>
</div>
```

Let's say the Image has a width of 300px.

**CSS**

```
#header
{
     width:300px;
     height:100px;
     background-image: url("header.png");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#middle
{    width:300px;
     height:400px;
     background-image: url("middle.png");
     background-repeat: repeat-y;
     /*If the width will be bigger than the actual
       width of the image, then add:
       background-repeat: repeat-x;
     */
}
#footer
{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-image: url("footer.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

More about [background-repeat](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp).

Note that the image will be repeated, which won't look really good, I suggest that give the middle a fixed height, and use, `overflow:auto;` which will create a scrollbar when contents exceeds the size.

Comment: Don't forget to mention `background-repeat` can be also `repeat-x` and `repeat`, and `no-repeat` :) you need to add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to `#header` and `#footer` as well, as it was part of the question

Comment: Thanks @Morpheus I updated the solution, the reason why I didn't add `no-repeat` to `#header` and `#footer` because I thought he would be giving them the exact `width` and `height` of `header.png` and `footer.png`.